# In react how do I get only the last value for a onchange function

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I'm new to react.
I'd like to collect the value from an input in an array of objects.
But on the input's onChange it adds all the letters to the array.
I'd like to collect only the last entry.
How may I do that ?

```
 <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Ecrivez votre question"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  let tab = [...questionsTitle];
                  tab.push({
                    index: index,
                    type: questionType[index],
                    title: event.target.value,
                  });
                  setQuestionsTitle(tab);
                }}
              ></input>
```

As you can see on the screenshot, my array is very long. How can I get the value without going through all the letters ?

I thanks you in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww9L5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the value if it already exist otherwise push the new object. Below is the sample code

```
<input
type="text"
placeholder="Ecrivez votre question"
onChange={(event) => {
    let tab = [...questionsTitle];
    let tabIndex = tab.findIndex(x => x.index === index);
    if (tabIndex !== -1) {
        tab[tabIndex].type = questionType[index]
        tab[tabIndex].title = event.target.value
    } else {
        tab.push({
            index: index,
            type: questionType[index],
            title: event.target.value,
        });
    }
    setQuestionsTitle(tab);
}}
```

> 

Comment: It works, thank you !
Could you explain to me this line ?
 let tabIndex = tab.findIndex(x => x.index === index);
I dont understand this part : x => x.index

Comment: In this line, we are checking the index of the current object. if exist then we'll update the existing object by index otherwise, we'll push the new object.

Comment: Ok. It was the first time I saw it written like this.
Thank you very much for you explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the last by using square brackets e.g event.target.value[-1]
You can copy below code.

```
 <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ecrivez votre question"
            onChange={(event) => {
              let tab = [...questionsTitle];
              tab.push({
                index: index,
                type: questionType[index],
                title: event.target.value[-1],
              });
              setQuestionsTitle(tab);
            }}
          ></input>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It doesn't work.
I still have a lot of entries but now title is undefined.

Comment: i had to get the length of the ```let length = e.target.value.length;``` first, then ```setAnswer(e.target.value[length - 1])```